# Let $V = \text{span}\{x_1,x_2\}$ , where $x_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and $x_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $ .

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $V = span\{x_1,x_2\}$ , where $$x_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
6 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$  and $$x_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}
$$ . Then orthogonal basis $(v_1,v_2)$ for $V$ is given by

1. $$v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
   3 \\
   6 \\
   0
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$ , $$v_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   1
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
2. $$v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
   3 \\
   6 \\
   0
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$ , $$v_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   2
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
3. $$v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
   3 \\
   0 \\
   6
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$ , $$v_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\
   0 \\
   0
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
4. $$v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
   3 \\
   0 \\
   6
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$,$$v_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   2
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$

We know that if $V = \{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\}$ be the set of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ then $S$ is called an orthogonal if $v_i•v_j = 0, \forall i \neq j$. Here all options satisfy above property. I think all options are correct but I'm not sure. Please help me.

Comment: you need to verify  if $v_1,v_2$ are both linear combinations of $x_1,x_2$.

Comment: Could you try to be a bit clearer about what don't understand ? I do not really see your question here.

Comment: I swear the 3rd and 4th options, the vectors are not orthogonal, unless the dot product I am thinking is not the same as the one you are thinking

Comment: Options 1-2 are the same, meaning: the span of both vectors in 1 and in 2 is the very same.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about the question

$V = span  \left(\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6\\0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\2
\end{bmatrix}\right) ~$  of  $~\mathbb{R}^3 $ with basis $\vec x_{1}= \begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6\\0
\end{bmatrix} $ and $\vec x_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\2
\end{bmatrix} $

Note :

1. Orthonormal vectors have a length of one unit
2. Orthonormal vectors are orthogonal to each other. Their dot product
   should be zero.

Finding orthonormal basis :

$\vec u_{1} = \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{\vec x_{1}} \| } \cdot \vec x_{1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{45}}  \begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6\\0
\end{bmatrix} $

To find $~ \vec u_{2} $ we need following equations :

$$ \vec x_{2} = \vec x^{||}_{2} + \vec x^{\perp }_{2}$$
$$ \vec x^{\perp}_{2} =  \vec x_{2} - \vec x^{||}_{2} =  \vec x_{2} - proj_{L} \vec x_{2} = \vec x_{2} - \left( \vec u_{1} \cdot \vec x_{2} \right) \vec u_{1}$$

the equations basically means, finding $ \vec x^{\perp}_{2}$  of $\vec x_{2}$ which is orthogonal to a line spanned by $\vec u_{1}$, in turn orthogonal to the $\vec u_{1}$.

$  \vec x^{\perp}_{2} =  \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\2
\end{bmatrix} - \left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{45}}  \begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6\\0
\end{bmatrix} \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\2
\end{bmatrix} \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{45}}  \begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6\\0
\end{bmatrix} $

$  \vec x^{\perp}_{2} =   \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\2
\end{bmatrix} - \frac{15}{45} \begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6\\0 \end{bmatrix} $

$  \vec x^{\perp}_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\2 \end{bmatrix} $

$\vec u_{2} = \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{\vec x^{\perp}_{2}} \| } \cdot \vec x^{\perp}_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\1 \end{bmatrix} $

---

$\vec u_{1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{45}}  \begin{bmatrix}
3\\
6\\0
\end{bmatrix} ,  ~\vec u_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\1 \end{bmatrix} $

Form orthonormal basis of $V$. Their dot product is zero and their lengths  are one units